Not able to download asset in flutter
I have a portfolio project in which the resume is in the pdf form in asset folder. I want to get the resume downloaded when clicking on the download button. I tried many packages but not able to get the required functionality. Anyone have any lead.
I have tried many packages but no one is able to download the pdf file from the asset folder

do you mean, you want the users of your app to be able to save the pdf to their device?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please specify your target build. Is it web or is it other builds like android?

yup, I have a resume in pdf format in the asset folder, i am willing to provide a download button through which the users(HRs , job Providers) would be able to download the pdf onto their device.

Target audience is web, but i am willing to make it work on both android and web

you can use https://aimensayoud.medium.com/save-an-image-from-assets-to-the-phone-storage-in-flutter-2-2-7d3aba10b5ad . But use permission handler for latest changes in device of API lavel 33.

Check this issue on Stackoverflow This has answer to your problem.

To achieve this, you can load the PDF from the app's assets and then write it to the device's storage. Here's how I implemented it in one of my Flutter projects.
First, you’ll need to add the following dependencies in pubspec.yaml:
dependencies:
path_provider: ^2.0.12
permission_handler: ^10.2.0
after adding this
try this function in your code. this worked for me .
ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('Your Asset Path'); 

    List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();

above converting to bytes
    Directory directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();

write the permission handling code if necessary
    String path = directory.path;

    File file = File('$path/sample.pdf');

    await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);

Try this one

Not able to get it. I am writing the functionality in the floating action button can you provide me with proper code or any references
